# How can I make my app more responsive and handle different screen size?

Tags: flutter, dart

Any help is appreciated! I've been to trying to figure out why my app doesn't handle different screen size.. I added `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` inside a container to make it more responsive, however, still not responsive. only it's responsive on ios simulator with the overflow error.. not on android simulator. What am I doing wrong?!

How can I make my app handle different screen size both on android and ios simulator?

```
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade200,
              title: Text('Weather App', style: GoogleFonts.roboto()),
              bottom: 
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      icon: FaIcon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidSun,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Tab(
                        icon: Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    )),
                  ]),
            ),
            body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      colors: [Colors.deepOrange.shade400, Colors.white],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const ForecastWeather(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120.0),
                            child: Weather(weather: weatherData),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width , thats mean its calculate all of the screen width, and you can confirm it with print this, so what i did, use a package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil , i think you can follow this, they also use media query .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is main.dart file could u try like this?

```
class AppName extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Go home_page.dart and do there.

```
  class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container( //this container can be your background.dart or whatever u want
      height: size.height * 1,
      width: size.width * 1,
    );
  }
}
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goal. Do you want different behavior on different Screen sizes or do you just want to arrange your Elements to get a lean experience on all devices?

If it is the second, then it's not practical to use MediaQueries to measure it all by yourself. Instead try to learn and use flutters [layouting](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout).
Here is a Basics Codelab for that:
https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics

For basic responsive Design without fancy stuff like different layouts for Tables or Foldables, it's way easier to handle it with Layout Design.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) in my application.

Initallize it with your design size.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(
      BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      orientation: Orientation.portrait);
  return Scaffold();
}
```

And use like this:

```
Container(
  width: 50.w,
  height:200.h
)
```

This turns 50 dp in your design responsive. Check out their documentation for more information.